# Von Neumann Equation Density Matrix Implementation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to implement the von Neumann Equation for a given 4x4 density Matrix with a time dependent Hamiltonian `Hp[t_]` in Mathematica but I get stuck.

```
Format[y[a__]] := Subscript[y, a]
rho[t_] := Array[x[##][t] &, {4, 4}]

sol = NDSolve[{I*rho'[t] == Hp[t].rho[t] - rho[t].Hp[t], 
   rho[0] == rhoIni}, {rho}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

However I only get the output

```
{{rho -> rho}}
```

So I guess something is structurally wrong with my code. I try to extract a solution by writing

```
rho[t_] = rho[t] /. sol
```

My Initial Condition is

```
{{0.261068, 0.190226, 0.148085, -0.190226}, {0.190226, 0.238932, 
  0.190226, -0.141687}, {0.148085, 0.190226, 
  0.261068, -0.190226}, {-0.190226, -0.141687, -0.190226, 0.238932}}
```

And the Hamiltonian is defined by:

```
Hp[t_] = {{1 + 0.1*Sin[t], -1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 
   1 - 0.1*Sin[t], 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}
```

But this doesn't work as there is no solution anyways.
Maybe you can help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should avoid using single Capital letters in your variable definitions because capital letters may intervene Mathematica Built-in functions. For example, `I` which you use may cause problems. What is `I`?

Comment: Please define  the Hamiltonian `Hp[t]`  and the initial conditions.

Comment: @TugrulTemel The I is the symbol for the imaginary number in Mathematica

Comment: @DanielHuber I added the Hamiltonian and the inital conditions

Comment: @Interestedbutnotknowing: Imaginary number in Mathematica is `Im`

Comment: There's a simple mistake in your `NDSolve` setup: solve for `rho[t]` instead of `{rho}`. Like this: `NDSolve[{I*rho'[t] == Hp[t] . rho[t] - rho[t] . Hp[t], rho[0] == rhoIni}, rho[t], {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @Tugrul Temel the built-in imaginary unit in Mathematica is, in fact `I`. `Im` is the built-in function which takes the imaginary part of a complex number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't define `rho` as an explicit matrix:

```
Hp[t_]={{1+0.1*Sin[t],-1,0,1},{-1,0,-1,0},{0,-1,1-0.1*Sin[t],1},{1,0,1,0}};
rhoIni={
    {0.261068,0.190226,0.148085,-0.190226},
    {0.190226,0.238932,0.190226,-0.141687},
    {0.148085,0.190226,0.261068,-0.190226},
    {-0.190226,-0.141687,-0.190226,0.238932}
};

Clear[rho]
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {I*rho'[t] == Hp[t].rho[t]-rho[t].Hp[t], rho[0]==rhoIni},
    rho,
    {t,0,10}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[Abs[sol[x]],{x,0,10}]
```

[image]